# How do you configure Amplify using only the auth package?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Using just the auth package (not `aws-sdk`) how can I configure Amplify with my credentials?

```
const {
  Auth,
  // configure?
} = require('@aws-amplify/auth')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `configure` method on the `Auth` class.
Example:

```
Auth.configure({
  region: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_REGION,
  userPoolId: import.meta.env.VITE_USER_POOL_ID,
  userPoolWebClientId: import.meta.env.VITE_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/6882c5e6e8f1bff2206ff0de74cebbcf87efd622/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L141

Answer (score 1):

This is another example from Amplify doc. You have more option params to make it customized. Let me know if have more question.

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // (required) only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

    // (required)- Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

    // (optional) - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region
    // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
    identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

    // (optional) - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

    // (optional) - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string, App client secret needs to be disabled)
    userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

    // (optional) - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
    mandatorySignIn: false,

    // (optional) - Configuration for cookie storage
    // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
    cookieStorage: {
      // - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
      domain: '.yourdomain.com',
      // (optional) - Cookie path
      path: '/',
      // (optional) - Cookie expiration in days
      expires: 365,
      // (optional) - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
      sameSite: 'strict' | 'lax',
      // (optional) - Cookie secure flag
      // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
      secure: true
    },

    // (optional) - customized storage object
    storage: MyStorage,

    // (optional) - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

    // (optional) - Manually set key value pairs that can be passed to Cognito Lambda Triggers
    clientMetadata: { myCustomKey: 'myCustomValue' },

    // (optional) - Hosted UI configuration
    oauth: {
      domain: 'your_cognito_domain',
      scope: [
        'phone',
        'email',
        'profile',
        'openid',
        'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'
      ],
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      clientId: '1g0nnr4h99a3sd0vfs9',
      responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
    }
  }
});
```

Reference: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/#top-level-configuration